# How to change React Base URL from localhost to my custom domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-scripts

I just created my react-app and everything is working on my localhost also connecting to backend app through API which i configured, Now I just deployed my react app to nginx server after running `yarn run build` and i uploaded the build folder to my server root directory. The home page was serve and other page which needn't to connect to the server was serve as well but when I try to login I got an error and from the error I realised my app was sending request to `http://localhost:3000/v1/auth/login` instead of `http://api.mysite.com/v1/auth/login` How do I make this changes before building my react app. Below is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "mysite",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "https://api.mysite.com",
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/dayjs": "^2.16.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.2",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.17",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers-pro": "^5.0.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "mdb-react-ui-kit": "^4.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-bootstrap-submenu": "^2.0.0",
    "react-countdown": "^2.3.5",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.7.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.2.9",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^3.1.0",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.2.9",
    "react-pro-sidebar": "^1.0.0-alpha.7",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.0-beta.10",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.6.1",
    "react-simple-star-rating": "^4.0.5",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.1.3",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "swiper": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.18.9",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.2",
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "styled-components": "^5",
    "//": "See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773",
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried reverse proxy in NGINX

Comment: @SanuKhan No I haven't I think this should be react problem and should be fixed before build but I don't know how to go about it

Comment: You are using fetch or axios to call your api?  if yes, you might need to change your base url before build

Comment: @SanuKhan I use axios and i change my base URL already

Answer (score 1):

Proxies only work for the dev server and don't work in production. You'll have to create an env file and use that instead. Here's how you'd do it:

```
// .env
REACT_APP_APP_HOST='https://api.mysite.com'

process.env.REACT_APP_APP_HOST // use this to access your api
```

Comment: this sound interesting, so inside which directory am I suppose to add this .env file at the root of my react app along side with package.json file or where should this .evn file be?

Comment: Yup, at the root along side with package.json